# How justify text using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, itext

Have piece of code like below:

```
 var workStream = new MemoryStream();
 var doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
 PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, workStream).CloseStream = false;
 doc.Open();

 var builder = new StringBuilder();
 builder.Append("MY LONG HTML TEXT");
 var parsedHtmlElements = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(builder.ToString()), null);

 foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
       doc.Add(htmlElement);

doc.Close();

byte[] byteInfo = workStream.ToArray();
workStream.Write(byteInfo, 0, byteInfo.Length);
workStream.Position = 0;
return new FileStreamResult(workStream, "application/pdf")
```

And have one problem-how make that pdf justified? Is any method or something which quickly do that?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you are trying to do. Please clarify  what "make that pdf adjusted" means.

Comment: Something like CRTL+J in MS Word,aligh lines to left and right side of the page in the same time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah, I get it, you mean "justified" instead of "adjusted". I updated your question. It's actually pretty easy. Basically it depends on the type of content that you're adding and whether that content supports this concept in the first place. Assuming that you have basic paragraphs you can set the `Alignment` property on them before adding them in your main loop:

```
foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements){
    //If the current element is a paragraph
    if (htmlElement is Paragraph){
        //Set its alignment
        ((Paragraph)htmlElement).Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
    }
    doc.Add(htmlElement);
}
```

There's two types of justification, `Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED` and `Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED_ALL`. The second is the same as the first except that it also justifies the last line of text which you may or may not want to do.