# How to align two paragraphs to the left and right on the same line?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I want to display two pieces of content (it may a paragraph or text) to the left and right side on a single line. My output should be like

```
 Name:ABC                                                               date:2015-03-02
```

How can I do this?

Comment: @Jongware I don't think the question is about justifying text. I think it's about right and left aligning strings. I have provided an answer with several options, including the one you refer to, and I have explained why I think your pointer doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie: correct; OP clarfied his original post afterwards.

Comment: @Jongware Aha, I missed that part. I wondered why he didn't use any spaces in his left and right string ;-) I just checked the original question and I am happy to see that the bad code was removed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please take a look at the [LeftRight](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/objects/LeftRight) example. It offers two different solutions for your problem:

[image]

**Solution 1:** Use glue

By glue, I mean a special `Chunk` that acts like a separator that separates two (or more) other `Chunk` objects:

```
Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Text to the left");
p.add(glue);
p.add("Text to the right");
document.add(p);
```

This way, you will have `"Text to the left"` on the left side and `"Text to the right"` on the right side.

**Solution 2:** use a `PdfPTable`

Suppose that some day, somebody asks you to put something in the middle too, then using `PdfPTable` is the most future-proof solution:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
table.setWidthPercentage(100);
table.addCell(getCell("Text to the left", PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT));
table.addCell(getCell("Text in the middle", PdfPCell.ALIGN_CENTER));
table.addCell(getCell("Text to the right", PdfPCell.ALIGN_RIGHT));
document.add(table);
```

In your case, you only need something to the left and something to the right, so you need to create a table with only two columns: `table = new PdfPTable(2)`.

In case you wander about the `getCell()` method, this is what it looks like:

```
public PdfPCell getCell(String text, int alignment) {
    PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(text));
    cell.setPadding(0);
    cell.setHorizontalAlignment(alignment);
    cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
    return cell;
}
```

**Solution 3:** Justify text

This is explained in the answer to this question: [How justify text using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10145557/how-justify-text-using-itextsharp)

However, this will lead to strange results as soon as there are spaces in your strings. For instance: it will work if you have `"Name:ABC"`. It won't work if you have `"Name: Bruno Lowagie"` as `"Bruno"` and `"Lowagie"` will move towards the middle if you justify the line.

Answer (score 0):

I did this to work and its working

```
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 30, 30, 100, 150);
            document.SetPageSize(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
            writer.PageEvent = new ITextEvents();
            document.Open();
            iTextSharp.text.Font fntHead2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bfntHead, 11, 1, BaseColor.BLACK);
            Paragraph para = new Paragraph();
            Chunk glue = new Chunk(new VerticalPositionMark());
            Phrase ph1 = new Phrase();

            Paragraph main = new Paragraph();
            ph1.Add(new Chunk("Left Side", fntHead2)); 
            ph1.Add(glue); // Here I add special chunk to the same phrase.    
            ph1.Add(new Chunk("Right Side", fntHead2)); 
            para.Add(ph1);
            document.Add(para);
```