# two phrases in the same line but different position - Itextsharp

Tags: itext

I am new to   generating the invoice using ItextSharp in C# . How can I  generate he PDF with  the following layout attached herewith

Customer Code - Test                         Customer Name - Test Customr
Invoice No - 122                             Invoice Date - 12/04/2016

Comment: Have you tried to do this with two column table?

Comment: Please can you give an example with two column table. It would be very appreciate

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575142/how-to-align-two-paragraphs-to-the-left-and-right-on-the-same-line

Comment: @lukbl I'd essentially call the current question a duplicate of that one; that one is for JAva but the concepts are trivial to translate to the .net world.

Answer (score 2):

Please read the [official documentation](http://developers.itextpdf.com/) and you'll find the answer to questions such as:

- [How to align two paragraphs to the left and right on the same line?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-align-two-paragraphs-left-and-right-same-line)
- [How to add a text to the left and to the right in a header?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-text-left-and-right-header)

There are also more general chapters, for instance the [Q&A about tables](http://developers.itextpdf.com/faq/category/tables). I'm mentioning this part of the site, because it looks as if you're trying to create a `PdfPTable`:

Try creating a table like this:

```
public static PdfPTable CreateFirstTable() {
  // a table with three columns
  PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
  // the cell object
  PdfPCell cell;
  // we add a cell with colspan 3
  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with colspan 3"));
  cell.Colspan = 3;
  table.AddCell(cell);
  // now we add a cell with rowspan 2
  cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell with rowspan 2"));
  cell.Rowspan = 2;
  table.AddCell(cell);
  // we add the four remaining cells with addCell()
  table.AddCell("row 1; cell 1");
  table.AddCell("row 1; cell 2");
  table.AddCell("row 2; cell 1");
  table.AddCell("row 2; cell 2");
  return table;
}
```

Now add this table to a `Document`:

```
document.add(CreateFirstTable());
```

This simple table should give you an idea on how the principle works. You need a table with two columns to which you can add as many cells with customer codes and invoices as you want.