# Fill spaces in PdfPCell with two text

Tags: c#, itext

I am using itextSharp 5 and trying to build index of a PDF file. Referring [How to align two paragraphs to the left and right on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575142/how-to-align-two-paragraphs-to-the-left-and-right-on-the-same-line)
to align two text differently(left and right)  in a single PdfPCell. Now I want to fill the spaces with dots(.) between this two text.[like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSauJ.png)

Can anybody suggest something?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For the dotted line, see http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-create-toc-when-merging-documents or read the answer to the duplicate question where we also use a `DottedLineSeparator`.

Comment: Thanks @BrunoLowagie