# iText7: How do I left align and right align two paragraphs on the same line without word wrapping?

Tags: itext, itext7

I am trying to accomplish the same thing that was asked here: [How to align two paragraphs to the left and right on the same line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29575142/how-to-align-two-paragraphs-to-the-left-and-right-on-the-same-line)

However, the question was asked 8 years ago and the answers are out of date. Itext has underwent many API changes since that question was answered (it is for itext5, I'm asking for help on itext7).

I've attempted to accomplish this with the following code:

```
var pl = new Paragraph("Left aligned text").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT);
var pr = new Paragraph("Right aligned text").SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.RIGHT);

float[] columns = { 0, 100, 0 };
var table = new Table(UnitValue.CreatePercentArray(columns)).UseAllAvailableWidth();
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(pl).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.AddCell(new Cell().SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
table.AddCell(new Cell().Add(pr).SetBorder(Border.NO_BORDER));
doc.Add(table);
```

Here's an example document containing *what I want* (at the top), and *what I'm seeing* (in the middle):

[image: Left and Right aligned text]

I tried removing the middle column and that worked as long as the left text or the right text didn't need more than half a page width. My use case has the left side being quite a bit longer than the right side. Giving the columns specific widths worked, but I don't know exactly how long each side will be (these strings will be localized).